# Phantom Nexus Group

Tags: nexus3

I have group in my maven-releases repository with no artifacts in it.

I have tried everything I could think of to delete it but my attempts have failed.

I am using Nexus OSS 3.

Can anyone tell me how I can delete the group?

Comment: should just be clicking on the repository in the admin panel and choosing `delete repository` ... what have your attempts been so far?

Comment: I don't want to delete the entire repository - just the phantom group 1 level down in the repository hierarchy.